# How to write a condition when selecting values in pandas dataframe using 'or'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

[image: screenshot of code I need to work]

Does anybody know how I can change my code so that it only displays values of 1 or 0 for each row in my dataframe for biasA and biasB (shown in the screenshot) - by this I mean no values of 0 and 0 for biasA and biasB. I have attempted to do this on the df1 line, and I have searched online and have not found anything. If anyone could let me know ASAP it would be great.

Comment: Please post code and any errors as text, not image.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Can use

```
df[(df.biasA==1)|(df.biasB==1)]
```

or

```
df[(df.biasA.eq(1))|(df.biasB.eq(1))]
```

Comment: `df[(df.biasA.eq(1))|(df.biasB.eq(1))]` will get you 1 and 1 if it exists. If you only need 1 and 1 please try `df[(df.biasA.eq(1))&(df.biasB.eq(1))]`

Comment: Was this helpful?